Importing a static method when not using a project structure
I'm trying to import the static method my_function into Main:
Main.java:
import static abc.my_function; // error

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        my_function();
    }
}

Abc.java:
public class Abc {
    public static void my_function() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}

But I'm getting the error "The import abc cannot be resolved." How can I resolve this issue?
Note: Both the files are in my working directory and I'm not using any project structure (in vs code).
project
├── Abc.java
└── Main.java

And Abc.my_function(); works.

You must put abc in a package (not the default package) if you want to import static.

you cannot import from the default package - the one without a name -  Java Language Specification 7.5.3. Single-Static-Import Declarations: "The class or interface must be either a member of a named package, or a member of a class or interface whose outermost lexically enclosing class or interface declaration (§8.1.3) is a member of a named package, or a compile-time error occurs." (original emphasis)

BTW Java Convention: use camel case for most identifiers and class names start with uppercase, (method names start with lowercase) -- class Abc and void myFunction()

Nope, import abc doesn't work but Abc.my_function(); does. @SitherTsering

In short, this is not possible. Your to-be-imported class has to be in a named package in order to be used in an import / import static statement.

As per my understanding its not possible to import static method in this way. Below is the reference link to get more details:
Invoking statically imported method with explicit type parameters
with-explicit-type-parameters
Instead you can try static call like below in your Main class:
abc.my_function();

have you checked the question you added the link to? How does it answer the question here?

That link is also showing static import is not possible and i have given solution in my anwser
